# Adding system call in latest kernel

Tags: kernel, 16.04

I tried to add a new system call in the system table.
As per the documentation,there should be a directory like `/arch/x86/syscalls`.
The `syscalls` directory is missing in kernel version `4.4.0-22-generic`
Can somebody help me in this issue and also I need information on how to add a system call to a system table in this kernel version.

Comment: You may be interested in this question over at U&L: [How to add a system call in linux kernel 4.x](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223888/how-to-add-a-system-call-in-linux-kernel-4-x).

Comment: Seems that [this file is missing in the stock ubuntu packages](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/233555).  This seems like a packaging problem to me.  I was able to install `linux-source`  package which did have these files in the kernel source tarball.  Extracting them & using this directory avoided any `syscall_32.tbl` include errors.

Answer (score 2):

The system call table in kernel `4.x` is located in:

```
linux-4.x/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl
```

and for 32 bit version:

```
linux-4.x/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl
```